# Compiling classes with numba?

Tags: python, class, numba

I am trying to use numba with a DACS pathfinding algorithm I wrote in Python. How do I spec something like "LiFoQueue" or a list of CPathNode class instances?

```
class CPathNode:
    def __init__ (self, node = -1, edge = -1):
        self.node = node
        self.edge = edge

dialHeapSpec = [
    ('route', CPathNode),
    ('nodeLists', np.int16[:]),
    ('pathCost', np.uin16[:]),
    ('finalCost', np.uin16[:]),
    ('nodeListLinks', np.in16[:]),
    ('predecessors', np.in16[:]),
    ('edges', np.in16[:]),
    ('dirtyIndex', np.uin16[:]),        # LiFoQueue?
    ('dirtyCost', np.uin16[:]),         # LiFoQueue?
    ('dirtyFinalCost', np.uin16[:]),    # LiFoQueue?
    ('maxNodes', int),
    ('costIndex', int),
    ('noCost', int),
    ('maxCost', int)
]

@jitclass(dialHeapSpec)
class CDialHeap:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.nodeLists = None
        self.dirtyIndex = None      # list of used nodeLists table entries
        self.nodeListLinks = None       # list of nodes with same position in costIndex
        self.predecessors = None
        self.edges = None
        self.pathCost = None
        self.finalCost = None
        self.dirtyCost = None       # list of used pathCost table entries
        self.dirtyFinalCost = None
        self.route = []
        self.maxNodes = int (0)
        self.costIndex = int (0)
        self.noCost = 65535
        self.maxCost = self.noCost - 1

    def Create (self, maxNodes):
        self.maxNodes = int (maxNodes)
        self.nodeLists = np.full (65536, int (-1), np.int16)
        self.pathCost = np.full (self.maxNodes, int (65535), np.uint16)
        self.finalCost = np.full (self.maxNodes, int (65535), np.uint16)
        self.nodeListLinks = np.full (self.maxNodes, int (-1), np.int16)
        self.predecessors = np.full (self.maxNodes, int (-1), np.int16)
        self.edges = np.zeros (self.maxNodes, np.int16)
        self.dirtyIndex = LifoQueue (maxsize = 65536)
        self.dirtyCost = LifoQueue (maxsize = 65536)
        self.dirtyFinalCost = LifoQueue (maxsize = maxNodes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Regarding de declaration of Jitclass fields, [*the tuples contain the name of the field and the **Numba type** of the field*](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html).

All fields must be declared as Numba types because *the data of a jitclass instance is allocated on the heap as a C-compatible structure so that any compiled functions can have direct access to the underlying data*.

This is very restrictive, and it excludes:

- Python types, like `int`, that must be replaced by `nb.int16`...
- Numpy arrays, that must be replaced by Numba array declarations `nb.int16[:]`...
- Python classes, like LiFoQueue
- ...

For example, the error you get for a field defined as `int` is:

```
TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got <class 'int'>
```